# Checking if person opening app is already an authenticated user FirebaseAuth swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I have an app that uses Facebook authentication to login. When the onboarding screen is loading I check to see if the user is already authenticated and perform a segue to the home screen if they are using the code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad(animated: BOOL) {
super.viewDidLoad(animated)
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
   performSegueWithIdentifier(loginSucessIdentifier, sender: self)
    }
}
```

The thing is, if I create a test user on facebook and then sign into the simulator device with the test user login info, when I open the app it still says I am the user, not the test user and when I go to Main screen it still pulls up my info.

I checked all the examples and docs for firebase and can't find a place where they do this initial check.

Can anyone explain if I am doing the check wrong or if there is something with the facebook test user I am not doing properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was. When a user clicks the signout button you also need to log out of facebook with FBSDKLoginKit. So when I signed back in it was still reading the credential from previous user facebook login.

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.logOut()
```